# Reading and Writing as Parallel Tasks

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, task-parallel-library

Looking for a best approach to reading from data source such as Azure Table Storage which is time consuming and converting the data in to json or csv and writing in to local file with file name depending on partition key.
One approach being considered is running the writing to file task on timer elapsed event trigger with fixed time interval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For things that do not parallize well (like I/O) the best thing to do is use the "Producer-Consumer model".

The way it works is you have one thread handling the non parallizeable task, all that task does is read in to a buffer. Then you have a set of parallel tasks that all read from the buffer and process the data, they then put the data in to another buffer when they are done processing the data. If you then need to write out the result again in a non parallizeable way you then have another single task writing out the result.

```
public Stream ProcessData(string filePath)
{
    using(var sourceCollection = new BlockingCollection<string>())
    using(var destinationCollection = new BlockingCollection<SomeClass>())
    {
        //Create a new background task to start reading in the file
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ReadInFile(filePath, sourceCollection), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

        //Create a new background task to process the read in lines as they come in
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => TransformToClass(sourceCollection, destinationCollection), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

        //Process the newly created objects as they are created on the same thread that we originally called the function with
        return TrasformToStream(destinationCollection);
    }
}

private static void ReadInFile(string filePath, BlockingCollection<string> collection)
{
    foreach(var line in File.ReadLines(filePath))
    {
        collection.Add(line);
    }

    //This lets the consumer know that we will not be adding any more items to the collection.
    collection.CompleteAdding();
}

private static void TransformToClass(BlockingCollection<string> source, BlockingCollection<SomeClass> dest)
{
    //GetConsumingEnumerable() will take items out of the collection and block the thread if there are no items available and CompleteAdding() has not been called yet.
    Parallel.ForEeach(source.GetConsumingEnumerable(), 
                      (line) => dest.Add(SomeClass.ExpensiveTransform(line));

    dest.CompleteAdding();
}

private static Stream TrasformToStream(BlockingCollection<SomeClass> source)
{
    var stream = new MemoryStream();
    foreach(var record in source.GetConsumingEnumerable())
    {
        record.Seralize(stream);
    }
    return stream;
}
```

I highly recommend you read the free book [Patterns for Parallel Programming](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19222), it goes in to some detail about this. There is a entire section explaining the Producer-Consumer model in detail.

**UPDATE**: For small performance boot use `GetConsumingPartitioner()` instead of `GetConsumingEnumerable()` from [Parallel Extension Extras](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/06/9990420.aspx) in the `Parallel.ForEach` loop. `ForEach` makes some assumptions about the `IEnumerable` being passed in that cause it to take extra locks out that it does not need to, by passing a partitioner instead of a enumerable it does not need to take those extra locks.

Comment: `GetConsumingEnumerable()` doesn't behave very well in `Parallel.ForEach()`. Consider using [`GetConsumingPartitioner()`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/06/9990420.aspx) instead.

Comment: Never knew of `GetConsumingPartitioner()`, I knew of the problems it address, I just did not know how to fix it.

Comment: i am getting this error "The collection has been disposed.\r\nObject name: 'BlockingCollection'"

Comment: @Seenu Then wherever you are initializeing the collection it is either explicitly getting disdposed or it is going out of scope and getting garbage collected. Fix it.